# IIS 7.5 default permission - is restriction needed?

Tags: iis-7.5

I am using IIS 7.5 and I do not need to explicitly specify permissions for my ISAPI application to execute.  Additionally, the application can **create subdirectories, create and delete files without me specifying permissions**.

Since I am using the **default permissions**, checked to see if web.config was safe from prying eyes over the web, and it can’t be read which is good.  My app also creates some .log and .ini files which are also not viewable over the web.  I did notice that .txt files are viewable.

I really don’t know how default permissions allow my app to do so much.  Is this safe or do I need to lock down? To be honest, **I don’t know what accounts to restrict**.

App details:

1. My ISAPI has an ‘allowed’ entry in ISAPI and CGI Restrictions
2. Folder and subfolders containing my application has ‘default’ permissions set.
3. Application pool is using ‘classic’ pipeline mode and no managed code.
4. Pass-through authentication in use.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it read by the web requester directly, then don't put it with your public files.

Have a secondary folder, outside your HTML root, that contains these private files. Then via your back-end application, fetch the files, process them, do whatever. But don't put them within your HTML root.